# In .Net xUnit project when I run tests I get an "Program does not contain a static 'Main'" error because of I referenced other project will be tested

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, nhibernate, xunit

I am working on a project and I get an error at this point. If I add references to other project in xunit test project named ECommercial.Core, I get an entry point error. There is no cyclic reference or something. On the other issues people get an error of having main method more than one but for me the error is there is any main method. And if I remove reference from test project, there is any problem. Tests methods are empty and there is nothing will cause an error inside methods. Here is error messages.

> #### Error Messages
>
> ----- Running tests in class "ECommercial.DataAccess.Tests.UnitTest1" -----
> For .NET Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0+7fb82e5b2
>
> CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable > > for an entry point
> [c:\Users\nihaSWin\Desktop\ECommercial\ECommercial.Core\ECommercial.Core.csproj]
>
> Build is fail
>
> CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
> [c:\Users\nihaSWin\Desktop\ECommercial\ECommercial.Core\ECommercial.Core.csproj]
> 0 Warning
> 1 Error
>
> Running time 00:00:00.68

How can I fix this ?
I have to add other projects to test them.

#### What I tried and didn't work

1. I tried to add dependencies as same with Core project
2. Upgrade sdk version to 4.5.2
3. Added <GenerateProgramFilefalse> false </GenerateProgramFile> property to property group
4. Regenerate whole project

test project folder name is ECommercial.DataAccess.Tests and there is only UnitTest1.cs project inside. The file code

```
using Xunit;
namespace ECommercial.DataAccess.Tests
{
public class UnitTest1
{

    [Fact]
    public void Get_Product_From_Table()
    {

    }
    [Fact]
    public void Get_Product_List_From_Table()
    {

    }
}
}
```

---

In the Ecommercial.Core folder which is referenced there is only IEntity empty interface and NHibernate Entity Repository file. Here is the file code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using ECommercial.Core.DataAccess.NHibernate.Helpers;
using ECommercial.Core.Entities;

namespace ECommercial.Core.DataAccess.NHibernate
{
    public class NHibernateIEntityRepository<TEntity>:IEntityRepository<TEntity> 
        where TEntity:class,IEntity,new()
    {
        private NHibernateHelper _nHibernateHelper;

        public NHibernateIEntityRepository(NHibernateHelper nHibernateHelper)
        {
            _nHibernateHelper = nHibernateHelper;
        }

        public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            using (var session=_nHibernateHelper.openSession()){
                session.Save(entity);
                return entity;
            }
        }

        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            using (var session=_nHibernateHelper.openSession()){
                session.Delete(entity);
            }
        }

        public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
        {
            using (var session=_nHibernateHelper.openSession()){
                TEntity result = session.Query<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(filter);
                return result;
            }
        }

        public List<TEntity> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
        {
            using (var session=_nHibernateHelper.openSession()){
                if(filter==null)
                    return session.Query<TEntity>().ToList();
                List<TEntity> result = session.Query<TEntity>().Where(filter).ToList();
                return result;
            }
        }

        public TEntity Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            using (var session=_nHibernateHelper.openSession()){
                session.Update(entity);
                return entity;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Core Project csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NHibernate" Version="5.3.3"/> 
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Test project csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="../ECommercial.Core/ECommercial.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your code, project file contents, and error messages as *text* within your question, instead of as images. They are fundamentally text files - we shouldn't have to click through to images to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thank you. There is nothing important in the code but I added it anyway.

Comment: And the error messages? Importantly, the error messages are referring to a project you haven't even mentioned in the question. (Ideally, you'd provide a [mcve] with everything we need... it should be as simple as possible, and complete here. In many cases, the process of coming up with a minimal example will help you solve the problem yourself.)

Comment: I did some changes. could you help me now ?

Comment: I'll have a look if I get a chance - but is NHibernate required in order to reproduce the problem? (Even if it is, I'd imagine you could make all those methods just throw an exception...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with NHibernate, or your test project. You can reproduce it trivially with this project file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You don't even need any C# code. Just build, and you'll get the same error.

This is because your SDK type is the Web SDK, which expects your project to be an executable.

Options:

- Change your SDK type (in the `Sdk` attribute) to just "Microsoft.NET.Sdk"
- Add `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>` to the property group

You only need *one* of these - I'd use the first unless you need to be using the Web SDK for some reason (which is entirely feasible).

Comment: Thanks for help. Problem's cause was new default empty web project and copy to the core project.

Comment: @NoStuff: Right. It's worth reflecting here on the diagnostic process of trying to reduce this to an absolute minimum. For example, the test project was a red herring - you didn't need that in order to reproduce the problem. Nor did you need the NHibernate reference. The more you can narrow things down, the easier it is to spot the real problem.

Comment: Yes, that's true but cause of why I didn't minimize it  I couldn't.I wasn't know where could be the problem. I knew there was any problem in code but the project structure and package managing was my lack. I am student and this is my first big project :). thank you again.

Comment: @NoStuff: That's why I'm saying you should reflect on it - so you can learn. For example, the error message said that the problem was in ECommercial.Core, so my first step would be trying to build *just* that project... if that failed (which it would have done) then you know the problem *isn't* about the test project at all. This sort of "divide and conquer" diagnostic skill is what you should be learning about as a student :)

Comment: I understand now. You wanted the error message and I realized what error actually says while editing the post. The problem was in core project. So, I removed all files in core project and error still there is and I really understand the problem in csproj file but how was I didn't know. After that I put the csproj code to the post which is right thing to do. But even so I was on doubt to put nhibernate codes because of think of if I am wrong :). I think I have got your adivces now

Comment: @NoStuff: And it's absolutely fine not to get right to the end by yourself - but if you do as many diagnostic steps as you can before asking the question, then it'll be easier to help you - and you may well be able to fix things yourself. If after today you're in a better position to apply those diagnostic steps yourself, that may be the most important lesson you'll learn this week or month. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks A lot @JonSkeet